# jqGrid inline-edit POST without editurl?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to find the information about editurl. Currently, i am working on the framework which does not permit editurl. The calls must go through javascript function which in-turn invokes the component on serverside.

Question is it possible to POST the data to **javascript function** instead of **editurl**?

I am experimenting with following:

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(">>>1");
    //--
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            result = a.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
            //---=
            var editActionOptions = {
                keys: true,
                url:null,
                oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                    console.log("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is editing.");
                },
                aftersavefunc: function (rowid, response, options) {
                    console.log("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is successfuly modified.");
                }
            };
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                datatype: "local",
                data:result,
                colModel: [
                    {
                        label: "Edit Actions",
                        name: "actions",
                        width: 100,
                        formatter: "actions",
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true,
                            editOptions: {},
                            addOptions: {},
                            delOptions: {}
                        }       
                    },
                    {
                        labe: 'ID',
                        name: 'empid',
                        width: 75
                    },
                    {
                        label : 'Name',
                        name: 'Name',
                        width: 140,
                        editable: true // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'dob',
                        name: 'dob',
                        width: 100,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'dln',
                        name: 'dln',
                        width: 120,
                        editable: true
                    }
                ],
                sortname: 'empid',
                loadonce: true,
                onSelectRow: editRow,
                onSave:onSaveRow,
                editParams: editActionOptions,
                width: 780,
                height: 400,
                rowNum: 150,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });               

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
            $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action); 
        var lastSelection;
        function editRow(id) {
            console.log(id);
            if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
                var grid = $("#jqGrid");
                grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastSelection);
                grid.jqGrid('editRow',id, {keys: true} );
                lastSelection = id;
            }
        };
        function onSaveRow(id){
            console.log(id);
        }
```

Comment: Please include the information about the version of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) in all questions, which you post. Free jqGrid allows to use callback function as the value of `editurl`. The parameters of `editurl` callback are: `rowid`, `editOrAdd` ("add" or "edit"), `postData`, `options`.

Comment: i am using commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS. Can you specify how it is done. I have already code listed above with edit event methods, but it never calls the function and editurl value is required too.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid I can't help you with Guriddo jqGrid JS. I'm not sure, what you mean exactly under "the framework, which does not permit editurl". Since the end of 2014 I develop alternative fork of jqGrid: "free jqGrid". I implemented many features, which close to your requirements: `url` and `mtype` as function (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.13.6/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L354-L359)). Moreover, one can use `editurl: 'clientArray'` and to use `afterAddRow`, `afterSetRow` and `afterDelRow`, which will be called inside of `addRowData` `setRowData` and `delRowData`.

Comment: By the way, you use Angular icon for your account. I'm working on providing TypeScript definition file for the free jqGrid. I plan to finish the work till the end of the month (till the publishing of the next version). You can see the current version of `free-jqgrid.d.ts` [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts). It contains already the definition of inline editing options, callbacks and events.

Comment: It is great work! looks like you have been using jqgrid for long time. -- Thanks for information

Comment: @Oleg does free jqGrid works with Bootstrap? what is major difference between Gurrido jqGrid vs Free ? it look to me the same? I am working with Salesforce1 based application.

Comment: Yes, of cause! You need just include Bootstrap CSS and add the option `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. See [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) for more detailed example. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap-tmplFilters.htm) is example of the usage Boostrap with jqGrid, together with some other options. It set `$.jgrid.defaults.guiStyle = "bootstrap";` and `$.jgrid.defaults.iconSet = "fontAwesome";` at the beginning to change jqGrid defaults.

Comment: It could be intersting to make double-click between to column headers to resize the grid to optimal width. Another feature, which can one see in the searching toolbar - `stype: "checkbox"`, which uses 3-state checkbox.